# How to make Android Lollipop remember wifi password?

Tags: wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop, password

I recently upgraded my Motorola Moto G OS to Android Lollipop. It works pretty well. However, one of the features I am missing is my corporate wifi being remembered that I used to enter from the browser. The browser used to ask if I want to remember the password and accordingly do so. I am not talking about saving the password while configuring the wifi in the settings UI.

However, since lollipop has this new UI opening up for entering password for wifi requiring authentication, I can no more save my password.

Is there anyway I can save my wifi password?

Comment: That's a so-called "captive portal". As I have not L-device: does that no longer open in the browser at all there?

Comment: No it doesn't. It opens in this, if you are correct, captive portal.

Comment: Could that be [this Lollipop bug](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/11/24/lollipop-bug-android-5-0-cant-connect-to-some-corporate-networks/), which is [also reported here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/7uHt17YM8K8)? If so, the second link has some screenshots – and also provides a work-around you could test.